# Linux Shell in C - warning: excess elements in struct initializer

Tags: c, linux, shell

I am trying to make a Linux shell in C but when I compile it says;

```
18710.c:13:20: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
     {"who", "who", "show who is logged on"},
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
18710.c:13:20: note: (near initialization for ‘list[0]’)
18710.c:14:20: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
     {"list", "ls", "list directory contents"},
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
18710.c:14:20: note: (near initialization for ‘list[1]’)
18710.c:15:23: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
     {"manual", "man", "an interface to the system reference manuals"},
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
18710.c:15:23: note: (near initialization for ‘list[2]’)
18710.c:16:26: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
     {"processes", "top", "display processes"},
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
18710.c:16:26: note: (near initialization for ‘list[3]’)
18710.c:17:24: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
     {"clear", "clear", "clear the terminal screen"},
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
18710.c:17:24: note: (near initialization for ‘list[4]’)
18710.c:18:22: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
     {"exit", "exit", "close the terminal screen"}
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
18710.c:18:22: note: (near initialization for ‘list[5]’)
```

Here is my structure;

```
typedef struct command{
    char *cmd;
    char *path;
}CMD;

CMD list[]={
    {"who", "who", "show who is logged on"},
    {"list", "ls", "list directory contents"},
    {"manual", "man", "an interface to the system reference manuals"},
    {"processes", "top", "display processes"},
    {"clear", "clear", "clear the terminal screen"},
    {"exit", "exit", "close the terminal screen"}
};
```

I know it is just a warning, but are there any other way for me to fix it? Can't I have 3rd parameter?
Many thanks

Comment: Your structure have two members, but you provide *three* strings to initialize each structure. What structure member is the last string supposed to initialize?

Comment: Yes it was so stupid mistake! Sorry to bother, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your struct does only have 2 (*cmd, *path) variables, and you are trying to initialize it with 3